# SQL Syntax Error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am sure this very simple, but I cant figure it out. I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY ID ( id , gets_mail ), `KEY email_addr ( email_addr ), ) ENGINE=MyISA' at line 9

in the following code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `ijgresearch`.`wp_post_notification_emails` (
`id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email_addr` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`gets_mail` INT( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`date_subscribed` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
`act_code` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`subscribe_ip` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`PRIMARY KEY ( ` id ` ),
`KEY ID ( ` id ` , ` gets_mail ` ),
`KEY email_addr ( ` email_addr ` ),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

and after many hours of trying different things, I cant get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Too many commas. It's why I put commas at the start of the line.

Comment: Stop using backticks if they are not needed. And if you do, do **not** include a space in the column name - because that then becomes part of the column name. I'm pretty sure you don't want a column name with a leading space: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10be9/1

Answer (score 0):

Too many backticks

```
CREATE TABLE `ijgresearch`.`wp_post_notification_emails` 
(
   `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `email_addr` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `gets_mail` INT( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
   `date_subscribed` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
   `act_code` VARCHAR( 32 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `subscribe_ip` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
   PRIMARY KEY (  id  ),
   KEY ID (  id  ,gets_mail ),
   KEY email_addr ( email_addr )
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and a comma too much before the last `)`